Can I just earn ETH by buying a stablecoin and then burn it getting someone's collateral back?
I am just learning how stablecoins work. And I learned that some of them work by requiring a user that wants to mint a token to provide some collateral that has to be worth more. I think it is call "Collateralized debt position". So my question is, when those tokens get transfered from one account to another, does the collateral do as well?
Because, it would mean that if I bought some stablecoins I could go to their smart contract and burn the coins and get the collateral back which is worth more than the coins I bought. So basically it's just free money.

Your collateral will be locked, if you transfer the tokens you borrowed, you will still owe the debt, and the collateral will still be at risk. If you can burn a token for more than it's wider market value luna/ust style, the difference gets arbitraged away.

@Maka thank you for the comment. So let me get this straight. I can go and burn the tokens I own and for this I will get the corresponding amount of the collateral asset? Like if it's ETH based, and the token is pegged to dollar, I get $10 worth of ETH for burning 10 tokens, right? I mean if I just bought these tokens and never minted them myself?

@Maka  I guess that this mechanism makes the token stay above the price of 1 dollar. But what then prevents them from rising above $1? What arbitrage opportunities are there to gain profit if the price of a stablecoin rises? Minting and selling them? But you won't get your collateral back unless you buy the tokens back and burn them.
